# How do I create an instance of a class, variably sized, at a specific memory location?

Tags: c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, placement-new, memory-mapping

I'm working on a project involving writing packets to a memory-mapped file. Our current strategy is to create a packet class containing the following members

```
uint32_t packetHeader;
uint8_t packetPayload[];
uint32_t packetChecksum;
```

When we create a packet, first we'd like to have its address in memory be a specified offset within the memory mapped file, which I think can be done with placement-`new()`. However, we'd also like for the `packetPayload` not to be a pointer to some memory from the heap, but contiguous with the rest of the class (so we can avoid `memcpy`ing from heap to our eventual output file)

i.e.

```
Memory

Beginning of class  | BOC + 4 | (length of Payload) |
Header                Payload   Checksum
```

Would this be achievable using a `length` argument for the Packet class constructor? Or would we have to template this class for variably sized payloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about trying to make that the layout of your class.  You'll be fighting against the C++ language all the day long.  Instead a class that provides access to the binary layout (in shared memory).  But the class instance itself will not be in shared memory.  And the byte range in shared/mapped memory will not be a C++ object at all, it just exists within the file mapping address range.

Presumably the length is fixed from the moment of creation?  If so, then you can safely cache the length, pointer to the checksum, etc in your accessor object.  Since this cache isn't inside the file, you can store whatever you want however you want without concern for its layout.  You can even use virtual member functions, because the v-table is going in the class instance, not the range of the binary file.

Also, given that this lives in shared memory, if there are multiple writers you'll have to be very careful to synchronize between them.  If you're just prepositioning a buffer in shared/mapped memory to avoid a copy later, but totally handing off ownership between processes so that the data is never shared by simultaneous accesses, it will be easier.  You also probably want to calculate the checksum once after all the data is written, instead of trying to keep it up-to-date (and risking data races in the process) for every single write into the buffer.

Comment: Length is fixed at creation, just couldn't be determined at compile time. So if I'm understanding you correctly, each member within the class (aside from payload length) would just be a pointer to the location within the memory mapped file of each field I care about? And yeah, we're simply prepositioning buffers to avoid copies. Only one thread at a time will ever have access to these buffers

Comment: You can have pointer members, you can have reference members, you can have member functions that calculate the offset from the initial pointer and return a reference.  You can have member functions that do complex operations on multiple pieces of the packet being managed.

Comment: The idea though is that you have a controller for your packet, which provides all the behavior of a packet.  The fact that the controller is not actually existing at the location of the packet is hidden behind encapsulation.  This is really common, for example if you have a printer class it isn't actually placed in printer memory, it is in the computer's memory but exposes all the operations of the printer.

Answer (score 0):

First remember, that you need to know what your payload length is, somehow. Either you specify it in your instance somewhere, or you template your class over the payload length.

Having said that - you will need one of:

- packetOffset being a pointer
- A payload length member
- A checksum offset member

and you'll want to use a [named constructor idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom) which takes the allocation length, and performs both the allocation and the setup of the offset/length/pointer member to a value corresponding to the length.

Comment: I wish a template was possible. But I don't think we can evaluate the payload sizes at compile time. Seems like that payload length member will be the way to go. Being that we want instances of the class to be located within a memory mapped region, would we be able to just set the payload pointer to (address of class instance + sizeof(packetHeader)) and happily store data there?

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, you need that length both for the allocation and for the construction, which is why I'm suggesting the named constructor idiom. Make sure it has access to an appropriate private constructor or access to data members. Also, a pointer may take up more space than an offset; may be more difficult for the compiler to optimize; will make copying more difficult; etc. I'd go with an offset or a length value.